# Bug with rendering <code>`TEST`</code>?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

There seems to be a bug with rendering the following snippet.

```
<code>`TEST`</code>
```

It is shown as `TEST` and should be visible with quotes.

Suprisingly the following works fine

```
<code>``</code>
```

and is displayed correctly ``` `` ```.

Comment: Inline HTML elements do not prevent further Markdown processing within them. The backticks *do* need to be escaped or they will simply be processed as another code element. This is by-design of the Markdown specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<code>\`TEST\`</code>
```

which makes:

`` `TEST` ``